# How to align two text as left and center without adding the paddingLeft, margin left ad right values in react-native

Tags: react-native, stylesheet

How to design a line with two texts one in the front and another in the center like below[image]

```
  <View style ={{flexDirection: 'row', flex:1,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
        borderBottomRightRadius:0,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
        borderTopRightRadius: 0,
        borderTopWidth: 0,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        marginBottom:5,
        marginTop: 5,
        borderLeftWidth:0,
        borderColor:'grey',
        borderRightWidth:0,
    }}>
        <Text style ={{fontSize:14,marginBottom:5}}> NAME </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <View style = {{justifyContent: 'center', flex:1, alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Text style = {{ fontSize: 14, textAlign:'center', marginBottom:5}}> 'SELECT' </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `wrap` the three `view` with outer main `view` and provide the middle `view` with `flex` of `80%` or something as your preference and give the `horizontal padding`.

For more detail you can look over here. [here](https://snack.expo.io/SJK3VhS9B)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something purely implemented using Flex.

```
<View
    style={{
      flexDirection: "row",
      width: "80%",
      height: 25
    }}
  >
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "flex-start",
        borderColor: "grey",
        borderBottomWidth: 1
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> NAME </Text>
    </View>
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "center",
        borderColor: "grey",
        borderBottomWidth: 1
      }}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, textAlign: "center" }}>'SELECT'</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
  </View>
  <View
    style={{
      flexDirection: "row",
      width: "80%",
      height: 25
    }}
  >
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "flex-start",
        borderColor: "grey",
        borderBottomWidth: 1
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> CLASS </Text>
    </View>
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "center",
        borderColor: "grey",
        borderBottomWidth: 1
      }}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, textAlign: "center" }}>'SELECT'</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, borderColor: "grey", borderBottomWidth: 1 }} />
  </View>
```

Comment: need to extend the line like the above image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy2q3.png

Comment: @sejn, Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I need like this. I posted the wrong image above. Here I need to align the NAME and SELECT in the same line. NAME is in right and SELECT is at center. Needs to have some space at the right. I need the length same as for the CLASS. Kindly refer here https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9KHG.png

Comment: @sejn, I have edited the answer, is this what you want? I haven't used margin or padding, only Flex.

Comment: Here If I select any values I need to show the text from center to right not from left to center. And some postion is cut off.Check with more than 15 char names instead of SELECT text

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as expected

```
               <View style={{flexDirection:"row", bottomBorderWidth:1}}>
                    <View style={{flex:1}}>
                        <Text style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start',}}> Name <Text/>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex:1}}>
                        <Text style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start',}}> SELECT <Text/>
                    </View>
                </View>
```